# inline-Assembler compiler error messages

Tags: inline-assembly

The machine i use is 64-bit, I wrote inline assembly code like this

```
__asm__ (
     "mov %cl TEMP_CHAR \n"
     "xor %eax, %eax \n"
     "mov %eax, A \n"
     "rcr %eax, %cl \n"
     "mov TEMP_B, %eax \n"
     )
```

Using gcc compiler, 
When I compile with it using commaand line
It turns out errors as follow

> /tmp/ccK8W7qx.s: Assembler messages:
>   /tmp/ccK8W7qx.s:177 : Error: suffix or operands invalid for 'rcr'

I wonder why this happens. Could anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0):

AT&T syntax has the operands the other way: `rcr %cl, %eax`. You'll probably want to change the other intructions, too.